# Access to the path "*****" is denied

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis-7

I have a folder in my same network as "\lo1dc\abcd\Admin\Images" I set full permission for everyone. I created a new web application in another machine within the same network and created a virtual directory called "_images" and set this folder path. I have set the path credential as a specified user while creating account and set the name as administrator. Which is administrator user for entire network.

Now while trying to save image as shown below

```
string strSaveLocationCode128 = Server.MapPath("~/_images") + "//abc.Jpg";
barcodeCode128Mobile.drawBarcode(strSaveLocationCode128);
```

This is showing me the error message as "Access to the path '\lo1dc\abcd\Admin\Images\abc.Jpg' is denied".

Please help me I am using Win 7 as my development platform.

Comment: What are the credentials for your application pool? Make sure you run it under the account that has permissions to access your remote location

Comment: I set the same credentials for application pool too.

Comment: What is the remote machine name? The path should look like this: \\remotemachinename\lo1dc\abcd\Admin\Images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found out the answer, The network path cannot be accessed by an anonymous user. So

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges
```

has done the trick for me.
Thank you all for your valuable help at right time.

Answer (score 0):

You can Login as local user using LogOnUser function:

```
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

        // types 
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

        // providers 
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1;
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2;
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;
```

**Usage:**

```
IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
LogonUser("User Name", "Domain Name", "Password", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token);

using (WindowsImpersonationContext user = new WindowsIdentity(token).Impersonate())
{
    // Do file operations here...
}
```